# What is the best way of sending huge amount of eth

Tags: blockchain

If i have to send 1000 ETH to an address which is the best way of sending it either as a single contract as a whole amount of ether or divide it as a 1000 contracts and each have 1eth per contract?
 Please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not directly involve programming.

Comment: Ask over at [Ethereum.SE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).